# Change a specific words color in a UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

## What I'm Trying

### Code

```
 func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    var output = " " + textView.text
    var outArray = output.components(separatedBy: " ").dropFirst()

    for W in outArray {
        if W == "//" {
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The problem I have is that I am trying to change the color of only a specific words (such as "//" would be red and "let" would be green) in the UITextView, so I was wondering how you might do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func getRanges(of string: String) -> [NSRange] {
        var ranges:[NSRange] = []
        if contains(string) {
            let words = self.components(separatedBy: " ")
            var position:Int = 0
            for word in words {
                if word.lowercased() == string.lowercased() {
                    let startIndex = position
                    let endIndex = word.count
                    let range = NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)
                    ranges.append(range)
                }
                position += (word.count + 1) 
            }
        }
        return ranges
    }
    func setColorToChar(_ chars: [String] , color: [UIColor]) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)

        if chars.count != color.count {
            fatalError("Colors are not added correctly")
        }

         //   let ranges = getRanges(of: char)
           for i in 0..<chars.count {
            let ranges = getRanges(of: chars[i])
            for range in ranges {
                attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color[i]], range: range)
            }
        }

        return attributedString
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextView.delegate = self 

    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

        textView.attributedText = textView.text.setColorToChar(["//","let"], color: [.red,.green])
    }


}
```

Result screenshot

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work because then say you have two things let and // let should be pink and // should be gray then it would set let but not //

Comment: also the console is throwing this:

Comment: 2018-04-24 14:40:58.479 Programe[2452:694872] -[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UIRemoteKeyboardWindow: 0x14d91c10; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x14d91df0>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.

Comment: You want to change the color of the word between @jwjbadger

Comment: Can you show how to do that? sorry I don't quite get what you mean @a.masri

Comment: @jwjbadger As in the question you want to change the color of one specific word within the UITextView and this is what the code in the answer if you want otherwise, please put it in question

Comment: @jwjbadger You have added the full `UIViewController` to see it

Comment: Do  you want to `//` be a red color and if there is a word `let` its color is a green

Comment: Ok now is it possible to make it so let and stuff won't work on a line with // but still work with let then like a variable name or something or something like that.

Comment: @jwjbadger I did not understand if you could explain more to me

Comment: So you know how in normal code if you type `// let` the let wouldn't be the color all keywords would be it would be the color of a comment can you do this?

Comment: but have it still work so if you did something like `let myVar: String = "Hi"` "Hi" would be a different color from String and myVar and let

Comment: The problem is that uses Swift 4.0 whereas I am using Swift 3.0 (and I am trying to use this in a app I am building that isn't only a editor)

Comment: try this in pod `pod 'Highlightr' , '1.1.0'`

Comment: Sorry is there a way to do this without using pods and or the github repository?

Comment: Ok , download this source and drag in your project 
https://github.com/raspu/Highlightr/releases/tag/1.1.0

Comment: Sorry I have a few pods in my project already is there a different way to do this without pods?

Comment: so without using the pods in the gut hub thing

Comment: @jwjbadger try clone github repo and add classes in your project

Comment: I can't because it requires pods and I'm not a admin so some of the files i can't open to see which pods to add to my pod file.

Comment: You can do this but you know that you are dealing with `git`

Comment: I know what I'm saying is do you know of code that could do that not requiring `git` or `cocoapods`

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily by making extension for `UITextView`

```
extension UITextView {
    func halfTextColorChange (fullText : String , changeText : String ) {

        let strNumber: NSString = fullText as NSString
        let range = (strNumber).range(of: changeText)
        let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: fullText)
        attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 76/255, blue:76/255, alpha: 1.0) , range: range)

        self.attributedText = attribute
    }
}
```

Usage

```
txtView.halfTextColorChange(fullText: "ABCXYZ", changeText: "XYZ")
```

Comment: Yes but I am trying to change the color not change the words

Comment: Its is changing color of specific text given in changeText, you can use it carefully with your textView delegate method "textDidChange" as per your OP requirement.

Comment: but I'm changing it to different colors so not every thing would be the same color